# Efficient VBA code for conditionally deleting rows in big excel sheet

Tags: performance, excel, vba

My excel sheet has 40 columns and more than 1,00,000 rows. I want to delete all the rows which contain cell with a string "NA" in any of the columns. I am struggling to find an efficient VB code for this, which doesn't cause excel to crash. 
My current VBA code (explained below) takes forever to run (>5 mins on Intel Xenon and 16 GB RAM) and crashes on slower machines (i5, 4 GB RAM). Any suggestions to streamline and make it faster?

P.S. Exact number of rows and columns are not known apriori. And, I'm new to VBA, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Link to the concerned file - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzl56SYDK-iRdTE1LTlYZGsxSE0/view?usp=sharing

My VBA code:

```
Sub DeleteRowWithContents()

'Finds the last non-blank cell on a sheet/range.

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long

    lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row

    lCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column

        'MsgBox "Last Row: " & lRow
        'MsgBox "Last Column: " & lCol


     For j = lCol To 1 Step -1
     For i = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, j).Value) = "NA" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=Range("A1"), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
    Next j


End Sub
```

Comment: @A.S.H Could you please provide a sample VB code for the above proposed combination

Comment: Is `NA` the whole cell content? or just "contains" `NA`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Comment: Protip: instead of "finding code for this on Stack Overflow", how about writing your own and understanding what you're doing?

Comment: Thanks for adding the code, that's a good first step towards getting your question back on track. Now you need a *clear problem statement*. Describe how your code is failing to do what you mean it to do =)

Comment: Now, I have explained the issues with my current VBA code.

Comment: How do I get my question back on track?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to 1. create an additional column and get the macro to write an "NA" into it, whenever "NA" is found wihthin the row and the line number else. 2. Sort the table using that column and delete all "NA" rows as block. 3. Resort the table using the row numbers and 4. delete the extra column.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample VB code for this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Would depend on the table layout of yours. Use a small copy, let's say the first 100 rows of your table, do all the steps and record with the macro recorder. For the check for "NA" just loop through the cells of a row.

Comment: @AkashMalhotra spoonfeedme.stackexchange.com has yet to come online.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest solution to this is as follows: ([Source](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1191894-efficient-vba-code-for-conditionally-deleting-rows-in-big-excel-sheet.html))

as this is a CSV file, parsing as text at the command line is likely the most efficient way;

if you're on a Unix machine (Linux or OS X) then you can use SED (stream editor) from the terminal. this processes the changes in under a second!

sed '/NA/d' ahs-comb-madhya_pradesh-dhar.csv > ahs-comb-madhya_pradesh-dhar_CLEAN.csv

I believe you could use PowerShell on Windows to do something similar, the below command appears to work, although takes about 7 seconds

Get-Content .\ahs-comb-madhya_pradesh-dhar.csv | Where-Object {$_ -CNotMatch 'NA'} | Set-Content ahs-comb-madhya_pradesh-dhar_CLEAN.csv